# In which category should my animation class go?

Tags: css, smacss

i am a newbie to SMACSS css.
I have this class which has a transition of like .5 seconds to it.
every time i want to add something to the div like an animation i attach a class. 
so should it be like in layout or state? like l-anim or is-anim?
please help.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be state. Layout's task - manage page geometry.

Comment: Thanks. should it be like s-anim?

Comment: i used to call statuses like is-animated, is-hidden, and so on. If you use s- prefix then yes.

Comment: Yeah i guess it's a state. is-animated is fine.

Comment: @evgeiny thanks. if you like this question please put a like up. thanks.